# Find text in VB6 IDE at the beginning of a line

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-6

I am trying to search a large VB6 project for where a variable gets assigned.  If I just use the Find dialog and enter the variable name in the “Find What” textbox, it opens many windows where the variable is *used*, but I would like to just get the lines where the variable is the first thing at the beginning of a line (where the variable is being assigned to).

I have tried using the “Use Pattern Matching” option, but I must not be using it correctly; when I search VB6 Help, it just says that option searches using  pattern matching characters, without mentioning what "pattern matching characters" are allowed.

Comment: Search the source using a text editor and a regex?

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Using an external text editor is a good solution; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that uses the VB6 editor using the VB6 Find dialog with the "Use Pattern Matching" option, to find lines where an assignment to a variable is made is:

```
yourVariableName*=
```

where the wildcard pattern matching character is used. It doesn't actually require the variable name to be at the start of a line,  and may give some extra hits, but is simple and easy to use within the VB6 code editor.

Comment: I was going to suggest the simpler "VariableName =" search, but neither that nor @StayOnTarget's solution handles the cases where the variable is assigned as a result of a ByRef function call.  In fact, I can't think of any search method, even with an external editor, that would find these cases, unless the editor actually does source code analysis.

Comment: @MarkMoulding I only made a small edit to this answer, just for the record.

Comment: @MarkMoulding That is the approach I usually use...  `VarName = `, with a single space before and after the `=`.  As the VB6 IDE doesn't support real regex, that's about the best you can ask for without 3rd-party tools (there may be some plugins I dont know that do it in the IDE, though).  As for the `ByRef` case, the only thing I've ever found useful for that is a watch with "Break when Value Changes" selected, and run the code over some useful portion.  Other than that, I can't think of any way to handle a `ByRef` set.

Comment: This link seems to have the wildcard characters that can be used in the VB6 Find dialog with the “Use Pattern Matching” option: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

If you can set your search mode to use regular expressions, you can indicate start of line with a caret.  ie, the "^"

FOO at start of line would be found by entering **^FOO** in the search box

Comment: The VB6 editor does not support regular expressions, but an external editor could work; thanks for the example.

Comment: I'd try @User51's solution first. If that for some reason gives unsatisfying results, I've used [TextCrawler](https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html) in the past for larger search and search & replace operations.